# Can we get notified after app is updated in play store in android

Tags: android

I don't know whether to ask this question or not, but please have a look at my question.

When I uploaded .apk in google play store, it will take sometime to update. After update every user got notification depending on connections and settings for update notification.

So, my question is "Can a developer who uploaded .apk will be notified as soon as that app is published and available on google play store"???

I don't know whether this is repeated question but I didn't got anything related to my question. If there is any other question I will sure delete this. But before that please help me with some links or KT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not for sure if I understand your question fully, but yes.  When the developer uploads the `apk` and publishes the application to the Google-Play Store, after the review and the application is accepted into the Google-Play Store, you will receive an email that you'r app has been successfully uploaded to the Google-Play Store.

I hope this answers your question. :)

Comment: No, I don't think so, Because I didn't got any mail for updated app. I only got the certificate of my app and that's all.

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044498/2127277